# onblur event execute after blur

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stuck on stranger issue on blur and onblur event on jquery. When you blur on input then onblur event execute first and .blur method. But when you call trigger .blur by clicling on anchor tag then .blur method execute first then onblur event. why this difference and any solution for this.[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3BDW/2/)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('a').click(function () {
                $('input').blur();
            })
        })

        function test() {
            alert(0);
        }
        $(function () {
            $('input').blur(function () {
                alert(1);
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" onblur="test()" />
    <a href="#">blur input</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note: Doing `$('input').blur()` doesn't make much sense, since only one item at a time has focus (if any). The fact that anything happens after using that syntax is because of jQuery (it fires handlers registered with it, plus tries to execute (in this example) `blur` and `onblur` attributes as functions. On the other hand, calling `blur()` on regular DOM node (like `$('input')[0].blur()`), that isn't currently focused doesn't have any effect (the blur handlers don't fire).*

I don't fully understand, why are you trying to do that, BUT if you insist on it and you want to, basically, make sure that your blur handler fires before the one defined in onblur attribute, you can use dual approach (using `jQuery.on` and regular handler register).
That way, either handler first or second handler will fire before the one assigned in attribute.

Basic example here http://jsfiddle.net/W3BDW/5/

It needs some tweaking, especially if you care that it may fire multiple times (in that case juggle the handlers dynamically, or store information somewhere, that event was already handled).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its happening that way as you mentioned in the question *`onblur event execute after blur`*

Your current code fires inline `onblur` first then the jQuery's `blur`.

Your code is working as intended but this is a better one with one `doc ready` and a function test outside of it.

```
function test() {
   alert(0);
}
$(function () {
   $('a').click(function () {
      $('input').blur();
   });

   $('input').blur(function () {
      alert(1);
   });
});
```

Comment: I don't know about you, but I'm always getting 0 first, then 1 (Chrome).

Comment: "This way i always get 0 first then 1" - yeah, you get 0 first then 1 even with the code OP posted, so I don't see a point of that sentence.

Comment: @insertusernamehere yes that's correct but i am unable to differentiate the question asked and output of the fiddle OP provided. It always `alert(0)` which is called from inline `onblur`. Whether my answer or his provided one.

Comment: @wtk: if you blur input you will get 0 then 1, but when you click on a tag you will get 1 then 0

Comment: @amit is it requirement or you have experienced this situation. can you plz give a browser name to test in that.

Comment: @Jai: It is requirement. I am using mozilla firefox

Comment: As a simple answer to that is `NO` can't be done, inline `onblur` always get fired first then the jquery's.

Comment: @jai: But when you click anchor tag and trigger blur then inline onblur is not getting fired at first

Comment: Whether you `tab` the input or `click` the link `onblur="test()"` **will always get fired first** and by the way i am also on firefox.

Comment: @jai: what are you getting by clicking the link

Comment: @jai: before clicking the link please reload your page once

Comment: @jai: can you come on chat ?

Comment: chat is blocked here can't come on it. sorry

Comment: @amit Maybe it would be much easier to help if you would say WHY are you trying to do this (relying on order of event execution) - is it a simple approach to solve bigger problem, or are you asking that just out of curiosity?

Comment: @WTK: actually we are adding function on inline onblur event and through aspx.cs file and passing some IDs with in. So i have to keep both the inline onblur event

Comment: @amit - you have to keep both, and I assume the order of handlers firing is important. I can't reproduce the invalid order (Firefox @ Ubuntu), but I updated your example http://jsfiddle.net/W3BDW/3/ for me, the order in output textarea is always "delegate", "attribute", "handler". Is it the same for you?

Comment: @wtk: In your fiddle when you tab input type textbox then output in textarea is delegate,attribute,handler. But when you click anchor 'blur input' then output is handler, attribute,attribute,delegate. This is the problem